# To show data in another div from other JSP on radio button click through ajax

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am trying to display other jsp content on radio click which is in another jsp through Ajax call.
Here is my radio button list code which is in order.jsp file

```
 <tr>
     <td>
     <h2>Payment Method</h2>
     <div id="demo" class="payment-method">
     <ul class=list-unstyled has-border-rigth">
     <li>
     <input type="radio" id="creditcardpayment" name="PaymentBrands" value=" Credit Card">
     <label for="creditcardpayment">Credit Card</label>
     </li>
     <li>
     <input type="radio" id="paypalpayment" name="PaymentBrands" value=" PayPal">
     <label for="paypalpayment">PayPal</label>
     </li>
     <li>
     <input type="radio" id="purchaseorderpayment" name="PaymentBrands" value="Purchase Order">
     <label for="purchaseorderpayment">Purchase Order</label>
     </li>
     </ul>
    <div id="result"></div>
     </div>
    </td>
     </tr>
```

Ajax code which is in order.jsp(same jsp) I tried three ways:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
    var PaymentBrands = $(this).val();
    alert(PaymentBrands);
    $.ajax({
       method:"POST",
       url:"modusTest.jsp",
       data: $('#result').serialize(),
       dataType: "html",
       success:function(response){
           $('#demo').text(response);
           }
        });

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
        var PaymentBrands = $(this).val();
        alert(PaymentBrands);
        $.ajax({
           url:"modusTest.jsp",
           method:"POST",
           data:{PaymentBrands:PaymentBrands},
           success:function(data){
               $('#result').html(data);
               }
            });

$(document).ready(function () {
var radioVal;
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
radioVal = $("[name=radio]:checked").val();
alert(radioVal);
$.post("/webapp/ecommerce/jsp/modusTest.jsp", {"processId": radioVal })
});
});
```

Below is modusTest.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
We are testing payment integration.
</head>
<body>

<p>&nbsp; Hello, how are you?</p>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Required solution as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the solution to what you want to do.

Your main HTML file

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<tr>
    <td>
        <h2>Payment Method</h2>
        <div id="demo" class="payment-method">
            <ul class=list-unstyled has-border-rigth">
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="creditcardpayment" name="PaymentBrands" value="Credit Card">
                    <label for="creditcardpayment">Credit Card</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="paypalpayment" name="PaymentBrands" value="PayPal">
                    <label for="paypalpayment">PayPal</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="purchaseorderpayment" name="PaymentBrands" value="Purchase Order">
                    <label for="purchaseorderpayment">Purchase Order</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="result"></div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var radioVal;
        $("input[type='radio']").click(function () {
            //use $(this).val() instead of checked $("[name=radio]:checked").val();            
            //this capture accurate & instant value. for more info read more about dom update  
            radioVal = $(this).val();
            alert(radioVal);
            $.ajax({
                url: "somefile.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: { PaymentBrands: $(this).val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#result').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Your jsp file will look the same

```
<html>
<head>
We are testing payment integration.
</head>
<body>

<p>&nbsp; Hello, how are you?</p>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Tried your solution but i want to show one jsp file whose code i give at last when i put name 'modusTest.jsp' in url under ajax that page is not coming